# How to set a starting solution in Pymoo

Tags: python, optimization, pymoo

i want to use a starting solution for pymoo in the algorithms NSGA2. For that I have the following code

```
intial_solution = ICSimulation.simulateDays_ConventionalControl()
algorithm = NSGA2(
    pop_size=5,
    n_offsprings=2,
    sampling=FloatRandomSampling(),
    crossover=SBX(prob=0.7, eta=20),
    mutation=PM(eta=40),
    eliminate_duplicates=True
)



algorithm.setup(problem, x0=intial_solution )
```

So i just create an `initial_solution` by using an external file that returns an `x` vector that is the vector of decision variables in pymoo for the evalutation. Then I add `algorithm.setup(problem, x0=intial_solution )`. When adding this line, the algorithm does not seem to terminate or to generally show some outputs. Further, in the evaluation method I can clearly see, that the algorithm, even in the first iteration, does not use the `inital_solution` as all solutions in the first iteration are just randomly generated as if there is no `inital_solution`.

So I want to know, how can I tell pymoo to use the `inital_solution` as a good starting point for the optimization instead of just radomly initiallyzing the inital solutions?

**Reminder**: Does anyone have an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The first iteration is randomly generated because you're setting `sampling=FloatRandomSampling()`. You should give your array of the initial design space instead.

For more info see here: https://pymoo.org/customization/initialization.html

Try this:

```
intial_solution = ICSimulation.simulateDays_ConventionalControl()
algorithm = NSGA2(
    pop_size=5,
    n_offsprings=2,
    sampling=intial_solution,
    crossover=SBX(prob=0.7, eta=20),
    mutation=PM(eta=40),
    eliminate_duplicates=True
)
```